# Is it possible to enforce that a type param is nullable on a class

Tags: c#, generics, nullable

given a class definition like:

```
public class Test<T>
{
    T _value;

    public void Test(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        if(_value.HasValue)
        {
            //stuff
        }
    }
 }
```

I would like to enforce that T is nullable so I can use the class like:

```
//does stuff
new Test<int?>(3).DoStuff();
//doesn't do stuff
new Test<int?>(null).DoStuff();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't enforce that `T` itself is a nullable value type, no. You can enforce that `T` is a *non-nullable* value type, however - and then use `T?` everywhere in the class.

```
public class Test<T> where T : struct
{
    T? _value;

    public void Test(T? value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        if(_value.HasValue)
        {
            //stuff
        }
    }
 }
```

One other peculiarity is that you can't constrain `T` to be *any* nullable type including reference types - and likewise you can't constrain `T` to be *any* value type including nullable value types. The `where T : class` constraint only works with classes (including delegate types) and interfaces, and the `where T : struct` constraint only with non-nullable value types (including enums).

Comment: On your last paragraph: I guess that's so you can't make a Nullable<Nullable<int>>? Or can you?

Comment: Nope, you can't (just checked). Makes sense to me!

Comment: FYI, in the original design and implementation of nullable types, the language designers considered allowing nullables of nullables, but ultimately decided to outlaw it. However, there is still code in the compiler for dealing with it, since those scenarios do come up in error cases, or when people type in crazy things in the IDE that the semantic analyzer needs to make a best guess at.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use `T?` or `Nullable<T>` as type parameter.

Then your sample becomes:

```
//does stuff
new Test<int>(3).DoStuff();
//doesn't do stuff
new Test<int>(null).DoStuff();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:-

```
public class Test<Nullable<T>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nullable types are essentially derived from the type `Nullable<T>`. Could you define your interface based upon `Nullable<T>`?

Comment: No, they're not derived from `Nullable<T>`. They can't be, as `Nullable<T>` is a struct. They're not derived from the `Nullable` class either, which is a static class.

Comment: True. Bad choice of words on my part. I was basically trying to ask the API couldn't be defined in terms of 'Nullable<T>'. I was struggling to see what stuff would be done in DoStuff() that required a generic type.